# How to change numbering of attachments

Tags: openoffice

I am making bachelor thesis in Open Office and I wonder how to change numbering, which I use for marking headlines, to lettering in attachements. When I change numbering in attachements to lettering, this change is appliedfor whole document. Do you know how to separatle set up lettering instead numbering?

Comment: Not much experience using OO.o, but I've found that LaTeX is so much easier than MSWord for these kinds of things...

Comment: I have written whole paper, so that's why I am not merging to LaTeX...

Answer (score 0):

Just create a custom style for the attachment's headings and define a separate numbering for those headings. This way, you can number thos headings independently from the "main" headings.

To get those custom headings into the TOC, you will have to select that style manually in the TOC options:
[image: TOC options]
After selection "Additional Styles", you can select the attachment-headings style from a list of styles.